# Value of $\sqrt[3]{\cos{40^{\circ}}}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

To find the value of $ \sqrt[3]{\cos{40^{\circ}}}$. Wolfram says it is a root of the cubic $8x^3-6x+1$ but how to prove that. 
Note that
$$(e^{i2\pi})^\frac{1}{9}=(\cos2\pi+i\sin2\pi)^\frac{1}{9}=(1)^\frac{1}{9}$$

Can anything be concluded from this?

Comment: $\cos 40^{\circ}$  is a root of $8x^3 - 6x + 1 = 0$, but that doesn't get you closer to working out $(\cos 40^{\circ})^{\frac 13}$. If you want to use this method, you'll in fact get a degree nine (nonic) equation to solve, i.e. $(\cos 40^{\circ})^{\frac 13}$ is a root of $8x^9 - 6x^3 + 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = \cos(40)^{\frac{1}{3}}$, then you have $x^{3}=\cos(40)$. Now note that $$\cos(120)=4\cos^{3}(40)-3\cos(40) \implies -\frac{1}{2}=4x^{9}-3x^3\implies 8x^{9}-6x^3+1=0$$

Comment: How did I miss this lol! Thanks!

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury Welcome. Do accept answer's once you feel your question has been answered :)

Comment: How do you go from $x^3 = \cos 40^{\circ}$ to $x = \cos 40^{\circ}$ (by way of simply substituting into the cubic?

Comment: @Deepak Looks like i made a mistake. Will edit. thanks

Comment: @S.C. See my comments under the question. If the OP really wants to compute the cube root of that value, he needs a nonic equation.

Comment: @Deepak Yes. I do believe that there is no shortcut for finding $\cos(40)$

Comment: @S.C. There is indeed a way to find a (probably messy) radical expression for $\cos 40^{\circ}$, since there is a well-known method to solve the general cubic in terms of radicals. However, since there is no general solution to polynomial equations of degree $5$ (quintic) and above, there is no obvious way to find the value of $\sqrt[3] {\cos 40^{\circ}}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$\cos 120^{\circ} = -\frac 12$

$\cos 3x = 4\cos^3 x - 3\cos x$.